# Java regex to grab table names before where

Tags: java, sql, regex, parsing

I  am stuck at writing a regex to grep a table name appearing before where clause..
Eg.

Select col_a,col_b from tbl_a left join tbl_c c , tbl_d v where a......

The output should be 
Tbl_a,
Tbl_c
Tbl_d

Comment: Could you please show the code you have trouble with? Note that there is no `Tbl_a`, `Tbl_c`  and `Tbl_d` in your example, only lowercased values like this.

Comment: Pls ignore the case

Comment: Something as simple as `(tbl_)\w` ?

Comment: Wish it was that simple, unfortunately Tbl_ doesn't always appear as a prefix

Comment: Can you perhaps show an example where that is not the case?